# RSI mostly due to keyboard or mouse?

Tags: ergonomics, repetitive-strain-injury

As I am in the software industry, I am in a higher risk group to develop RSI (Repetitive strain injury), and thus I am taking measures to prevent this from happening. I keep a relatively good measure and a good keyboard, but one thing that I have some questions about is that on several websites, one of the recommendations to prevent RSI is to use *keyboard shortcuts* more and use the *mouse* less.

From this it would seem that using the mouse makes the risk of RSI higher than the keyboard does. But is there any evidence backing this up? Is RSI mainly due to mouse usage rather than keyboard usage?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). Can you please spell out what does the acronym RSI stand for? Thanks!

Comment: @Lucky In my world RSI is Rapid Sequence Intubation, glad you asked for it to be spelled out :)

Comment: To also bump an old post, I meant: repetitive strain injury

Comment: Anecdotal evidence from my personal experience - mousing causes much more repetitive strain than a keyboard, because (1) its buttons usually require greater pressure, (2) it raises your hand higher than its natural position than a keyboard, (3) on a keyboard you have both hands symmetrical in the middle, with mousing you have one hand asymmetrical to the other which makes the spine twist; (4) it keeps you palm open and makes body heat release easier, which makes tendons more susceptible to injury in cold weather.